# SVN & Dreamweaver

Tags: svn, dreamweaver

I have a synology server which i have installed Subversion on, and i can browse to the repository using tortoiseSVN

svn://192.168.0.8/RepositoryName/RepositoryProject

all goo so far... but!

in dreamweaver CS6,

I have setup

Access: Subversion

Protocol: SVN

Serveraddress: 192.168.0.8

Repository Path: /RepositoryName/RepositoryProject

ServerPort : 3690

username: username

password: password

but i get this error:

**"server and project not accessable!('svn://192.168.0.8:3690/RepositoryName' isnt in the same repository as 'svn://192.168.0.8/RepositoryName')**

i have also tried for the server address : 192.168.0.8/RepositoryName

and i get the same error... it seems like its not picking up the RepositoryName.

Help please!

Answer (score 1):

I tried using dreamweaver with SVN myself and had issues like that. Additionally it seems that Dreamweaver can only support specific versions of SVN repositories.

I would suggest that you abandon the Dreamweaver SVN functionality, and choose a light weight SVN tool to keep track of your files after changing them to Dreamweaver (Like Tortoise SVN).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the following settings:

Access: Subversion

Protocol: HTTPS

Serveraddress: name-of-pc

Repository Path: /svn/RepositoryName

ServerPort : 8443

username: username

password: password

These setting will work in Dreamweaver CS6 and CC (2015).