# version control for adobe dreamweaver 6

Tags: version-control, adobe, dreamweaver

It is 2017, everything I have found thus far is for older versions. So- I was wondering if there is any modern way to connect GITHUB desktop to Dreamweaver 6. Not Dreamweaver CC. I have Dreamweaver 6-adobe.

Or any reasonably modern method for version control associated with Dreamweaver 6. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This link on stackoverflow references one specifically for adobe dreamweaver cs6:
[SVN & Dreamweaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396890/svn-dreamweaver).
it is still uptodate...64bit machines. TortoiseSVN(Free)
the download site is: https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html. thankc

Comment: personally i find the dreamweaver version of subversion control to be really difficult to understand. It seems easier(working alone) to just backup major changes to a backup folder than to weed through all the strange directions they offer. Sad.